# When to use lua_pop in C functions?

Tags: c++, lua, unreal-engine4, lua-table

I dont understand when i should use lua_pop, in this case stack grows in 5 each frame and reaches 10k then crash.

In this particullar case i call lua function which must return value.

Also, if table does not has function, i check is metatable has it in while loop. Does it make sense or there is better way to do that?

```
ModifierVariant_t LuaValue(FModifierParams_t& Params, const char* InName, int TableID)
{
    lua_State* L = FLua::State();
    const int Top = lua_gettop(L);
    FModifierParams_t* v = (FModifierParams_t*)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(FModifierParams_t));
    luaL_getmetatable(L, MOD_PARAMS_NAME);
    const int Arg = lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    memcpy(v, &Params, sizeof(FModifierParams_t));
    lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, TableID);
    const int Table = lua_gettop(L);
    int I = Table;
    SCRIPT_ASSERT(lua_istable(L, Table), TEXT("On top of the stack is not a table!"));
    lua_getfield(L, Table, InName);
    int Func = lua_gettop(L);
    while (!(lua_isfunction(L, Func)))
    {
        lua_getfield(L, I, "__index");
        I = lua_gettop(L);
        SCRIPT_ASSERT(!(lua_isnil(L, I) && lua_isnone(L, I)), TEXT("Function %hs could not be found!"), InName);
        lua_getfield(L, I, InName);
        Func = lua_gettop(L);
    }
    SCRIPT_ASSERT(lua_isfunction(L, Func), TEXT("Could not found a field %hs of meta %d, adress is %hs"), InName, TableID, lua_tostring(L, Table));
    lua_pushvalue(L, Table);
    lua_pushvalue(L, Arg);
#if !UE_BUILD_SHIPPING
    const int ErrCode = LUA_CALL(FLua::State(), 2, 1);

    if (ErrCode != LUA_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }

#else
    LUA_CALL(FLua::State(), 1, 0);
#endif

    ModifierVariant_t Result(0);
    UTIL_PrintF(SysEntity, "Lua stack size (after call) id %d", FLua::StackSize());

    switch (lua_type(L, -1)) {
    case LUA_TNUMBER:
        {
            Result = ModifierVariant_t(((float)lua_tonumber(L, -1)));
        }
    case LUA_TSTRING:
        {
            Result = ModifierVariant_t(lua_tostring(L, -1));
        }
    case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
        {
            Result = ModifierVariant_t(lua_toboolean(L, -1) == 1);
        }
    case LUA_TNIL:
        XASSERT(false, "ModifierVariant cannot be nil!");
        break;
    default:
        XASSERT(false, "ModifierVariant cannot be a pointer!");
        break;
    }

    return Result;
}
```

lua_settop in the end of the function doesnt work - freezes and then crash. Also lua_pop(L, 5) doesnt work too.